# Nth-child Combination to Skip 2 and then Select 3

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to know the `nth-child()` value of this:

1 2 **3 4 5** 6 7 **8 9 10**

I have searched in many references like [:nth Tester](https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/), [Mastering the :nth-child](http://nthmaster.com/) but couldn't find the combination I need.

I have also checked my combination on this [CSS3 :nth-child Calculator](http://nth-calculator.com/), it shows the combination like this:

```
:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+5):nth-child(n+8):nth-child(-n+10):nth-child(n+13)
```

Could anybody help me out to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34198474/1763929) answered good, however, you can achieve it even **shorter**, using [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot):

```css
li:not(:nth-child(5n+1)):not(:nth-child(5n+2)){
    background:gold;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Hi Vucho, thanks for your answer, is not() supportable to similar browser compatibility like the first answer...?? Is this code compatible to all browsers??

Comment: @SaurabhLP both are [CC3 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) so both anwers will work in the same browsers (in IE8 and below won't work) - [caniuse CSS3 selectors](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)

Comment: `li:not(:nth-child(5n+4)):not(:nth-child(5n+5)){...}` will skip every fourth and fifth element.

Answer (score 7):

You can combine several [`nth-child()` selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) to achieve your aim :

```css
li:nth-child(5n+3), /* Will select 3, 8, 13, 18...  */
li:nth-child(5n+4), /* Will select 4, 9, 14, 19...  */
li:nth-child(5n+5)  /* Will select 5, 10, 15,20...  */
{
  background:gold;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
li:not(:nth-child(4n+1)):not(:nth-child(4n+0)){
    background:gold;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
  <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
</ol>
```